# Swagger with Dropwizard APIs that use Generic types

Tags: swagger, dropwizard, generic-type-argument

I have a generic response object in my Dropwizard API with Response which is a wrapper containing a status enum and a value. The API operations have a reponse like Response or Response>.

I have been trying to find a way to handle this and saw some mentions that this is handled for Spring Rest / Swagger?

I am using:
        
            com.wordnik
            swagger-jaxrs_2.10
            1.3.5

Has anyone resolved this in a nice generic way?

Comment: Are you looking to have the wrapped part of your response be in the documentation? Or all parts of the response?

Comment: All parts of the response. For example I would like to see the properties of Pet being documented

Comment: I noticed that my post didnt render properly my example was
Response < Pet > and Response < List < Pet > >

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be looking for something like this:

```java
@GET
@Path("/pets")
@ApiOperation(value = "Get all pets.", response = Pet.class)
public Response<List<Pet>> getPets() {
  ...
}
```

Comment: But that doesnt contain the details of Response or List. The suggestion here is that the response is actually just a Pet object when really its a Response with a List of Pet's

Comment: Yeah - I think you may be out of luck with what Swagger provides out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Came around this old question as I was looking for a solution for the same issue.
Here is my workaround :

1. Create a wrapper class :

   ```
   @ApiModel
   public class PetListResponse extends Response<List<Pet>> {

       @Override
       @ApiModelProperty
       public List<Pet> getValue() {
           return super.getValue()
       }
   }
   ```
2. Override the response in the API :

   ```
   @GET
   @Path("/pets")
   @ApiOperation(value = "Get all pets.", response = PetListResponse.class)
   public Response<List<Pet>> getPets() {
    ...
   }
   ```
3. Success :)